# jSerialComm Java Serial Communication Fails Sometimes

Tags: java, serial-port, hardware

I am writing a java spring boot service that vends items from a vending machine using serial communication via jSerialComm library. Service sometimes work as expected and vends all items successfully but sometimes it fails to vend items, service is so unpredictable that it may fail at any stage of vending process.

Following is the service code that I have written:

```
package com.intelparcel.java.be.services;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.intelparcel.java.be.models.vend.FailedItemsModel;
import com.intelparcel.java.be.models.vend.VendRequestItemModel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class VendService {
private List<FailedItemsModel> failedItems = new ArrayList();

public List<FailedItemsModel> vendProducts(List<VendRequestItemModel> data) {
    failedItems.clear();
    SerialPort serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPort("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    serialPort.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, SerialPort.NO_PARITY);

    for (VendRequestItemModel item : data) {
        for (int quantity = 0; quantity < item.getQuantity(); quantity++) {
            openPort(serialPort);

            String TXBUF = "01C1" + Integer.toHexString(item.getSlot_number());
            System.out.println(TXBUF);
            byte CHK = 0;
            String[] HexValues = new String[TXBUF.length() / 2];
            byte[] ByteValues = new byte[TXBUF.length() / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < (TXBUF.length() / 2); i++) {
                HexValues[i] = TXBUF.substring((2 * i), (2 * i) + 2);
                ByteValues[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(HexValues[i], 16);
                if (i > 1) {
                    CHK += ByteValues[i];
                }
            }

            CHK = (byte) (0 - CHK);
            TXBUF += String.format("%02X", CHK) + ">";
            TXBUF = "<" + TXBUF;
            serialPort.writeBytes(TXBUF.getBytes(), TXBUF.length());
            System.out.println("Command Sent = " + TXBUF);

            //---sending command ends here-----

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                byte[] ANS_alpha = new byte[1024];
                serialPort.readBytes(ANS_alpha, ANS_alpha.length);
                logBytes(ANS_alpha);
                System.out.println("Initial Response: " + new String(ANS_alpha, 
      StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                if (new String(ANS_alpha, 
      StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toLowerCase().contains("01c100ff".toLowerCase())) {
                    flushAndClosePort(serialPort);
                    System.out.println("Slot is locked");
                    addFailedItems(item.getSlot_number(), -1, "Slot stuck");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    continue;
                }

                if (ANS_alpha[0] != 6) {
                    serialPort.flushIOBuffers();
                    flushAndClosePort(serialPort);
                    System.out.println("Did not receive 6...continuing forward...");
                    addFailedItems(item.getSlot_number(), -2, "Vending failed, please 
      retry");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    continue;
                }

                int count = 0;
                while (count <= 10) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    byte[] ANS = new byte[1024];
                    serialPort.readBytes(ANS, ANS.length);
                    String decodedResponse = new String(ANS, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    System.out.println("RESPONSE String: " + decodedResponse);
                    logBytes(ANS);
                    if 
     (decodedResponse.toLowerCase().contains("01c101fe".toLowerCase()) || 
     decodedResponse.toLowerCase().contains("01c100ff".toLowerCase())) {
                        if (new String(ANS, 
     StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toLowerCase().contains("01c100ff".toLowerCase())) {
                            System.out.println("Slot locked after vend");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    count++;
                }
                flushAndClosePort(serialPort);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return failedItems;
            }
        }
    }
    flushAndClosePort(serialPort);
    return failedItems;
}

private void flushAndClosePort(SerialPort serialPort) {
    serialPort.flushIOBuffers();
    serialPort.closePort();
}

private void addFailedItems(int slotNumber, int errorCode, String message) {
    failedItems.add(new FailedItemsModel(slotNumber, errorCode, message));
}

private void openPort(SerialPort serialPort) {
    if (serialPort.isOpen()) {
        flushAndClosePort(serialPort);
    }
    serialPort.flushIOBuffers();
    serialPort.openPort();
}

private void logBytes(byte[] bytesRead) {
        System.out.println("RAW_BYTES_RECEIVED: ");
        for (byte i : bytesRead) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Above code uses the SerialPort library from fazecast/jSerialComm to handle serial communication with the hardware device. The main function is vendProducts which takes a list of VendRequestItemModel objects as input and returns a list of FailedItemsModel objects.

The service loops through the list of VendRequestItemModel objects and for each item, it opens the serial port, constructs a command to vend the product, sends the command to the hardware device, reads the response, and closes the serial port.

If the response indicates that the product is successfully vended, the service moves to the next item in the list. If the response indicates that the slot is locked, the service adds the item to the list of failed items and waits for 5 seconds before moving to the next item. If the response indicates that vending failed, the service adds the item to the list of failed items and waits for 5 seconds before moving to the next item. If there is an exception while sending or receiving data from the hardware device, the service catches the exception and returns the list of failed items.

One important point though, when this code fails at any stage, machine does not send any response bytes back and then the server and the vending machines needs to be restarted in order for the code to work again but again, after restarting, this code fails on random points during the execution.

Comment: Maybe you need to enable a [flow control](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html#setFlowControl-int-)?

Comment: Do you have any examples of the failed communication? Does the wrong message get sent or recieved? Or is there an exception? ..

Comment: @B.Letz no exception, just receive 21 in bytes array

Comment: It kind of sounds to me like the clocks of the two communicating systems are not synchron. So it works for a while, but after some time the clocks are too different and the wrong data is read. The thing speaks against that theory is that you are using 9600 Baud and that is rather slow. So is should have more tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

While there are many possibilities, all the way down to electrical, a common programming reason for errors of this sort is related to incorrect assumptions around how the reading of serial port data works, especially when not using any flow control.

Using this line as an example:

```
  serialPort.readBytes(ANS_alpha, ANS_alpha.length);
```

If using blocking reads, then this might return before a complete "message" if a timeout occurs. i.e. Sender a little slower than usual. If using non-blocking, this might sometimes return before a complete "message". Your current logic flushes the receiving buffer before trying to read again. The sender *might* be hanging while trying to send the remaining bytes.

If you suspect this might be the problem, then  you would want to change your logic to continue calling readBytes until you know you have a complete message. Another quick check would be to use bytesAvailable/readBytes upon any errors to be sure to clear the sender before trying to read again. And similar, you might try bytesAvailable/readBytes upon connecting before trying to send anything.

Be sure to review the documentation for [readBytes](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html#readBytes-byte:A-long-) and check the com port timeout settings. It looks like you do not change the defaults, the defaults *might* be different per operating system.

Comment: not a real answer, those fake upvotes just for bounty are not much of a help either

Comment: lol. I can assure you, with the time it took to read through your question and code snippet, multiple times, looking for any obvious mistakes before writing about what I believe is one potential programming issue with the code, only to have you say this is a non-answer without acknowledging an understanding of the fundamental issue I described.... well, it was definitely not worth the points. You can have them back. :) Anyways, consider too that a truly canonical programming answer to a problem that is just as likely to be caused be hardware, is maybe impossible to provide.